# Separating a column value to two column as a record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like to get as Table B. how can I write a select query in MSSQL

[image]

[image]

Comment: You want to use a ROW_NUMBER() function (partitioning by employee and fieldtype, ordering by date desc presumably) then you want to pivot the results (or use conditional aggregation e.g. `MAX(CASE WHEN FieldType = 'Title' THEN FieldValue END)` etc)

Answer (score 0):

You can use stored procedure to copy records from another table.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CopyRecords]
(@TableBID int)
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO [TableB]
    ([EffectiveDate],[EmployeeName],
    [Title],[Department]) --- Columns of TableB table

SELECT [EffectiveDate],[EmployeeName],
    [FieldValue],[FieldType] ---Columns of TableA table
FROM [TableA]
WHERE TableAID = @TableBID --- Where value of TableAID of TableA table matches the value of @TableAID
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by conditional aggregation..

```
    SELECT [EFFECTIVE DATE],[EMPLOYEE NAME],
    MAX(CASE WHEN FieldType = 'Title' THEN FIELDVALUE end) as Title,
    MAX(CASE WHEN FieldType = 'Department' THEN FIELDVALUE end )as department
    from table_a group by [EMPLOYEE NAME],[EFFECTIVE DATE]
```

Comment: The MAX fieldvalue will just grab the last fieldvalue alphabetically. That's not necessarily the latest value (by date) in the field.

Comment: Thanks Karthikeyan. But I can't select with the value Latest EFFECTIVEDATE eg 1/1/2007. How can I correct  above query.I am strange with CASE WHEN syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
select A.EmployeeName, Title, Department, EffectiveDate
from (
        select      EmployeeName, EffectiveDate = max(EffectiveDate)
        from        TableA
        group by    EmployeeName
    ) A
inner join
(   select      EmployeeName, FieldType, FieldValue
    from        TableA
) src
pivot
(
    max(FieldValue) for FieldType in ([Title], [Department])
) piv on piv.EmployeeName = A.EmployeeName
```

Comment: Thanks. BhatiaAshish.It is working as expected. I also would like to link latest EffectiveDate.How can I continue.